# matrix path finder in python

Tags: python, matrix

So i'm working on a path finder project. It's basically a matrix with arrows and the program need to find the path to the destination based on the directions given by the arrow. So I have got the matrix with random numbers between 1 to 99. But i'm not quite sure how to add the arrows to the matrix. Basically I want something like this:

[example maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH8tz.png)

Arrows can be randomly chosen.This is my code so far:

def maze(c,r):
matrix = []
for i in range(r):
row = []
for j in range(c):
row.append(randint(1,99))
matrix.append(row)

```
for i in range(randint(0, c * r // 3)):
    matrix[randint(0, r - 1)][randint(0, c - 1)] =  '→'




matrix[0][0] = "S"
matrix[-1][-1] = "D"

print(matrix)
```

maze(6,5)
``

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking for help in printing the maze or finding the path through the maze?  What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.